# Как в метод передать ссылку на объект?

Tags: java, алгоритм, список, очередь

У меня есть метод. Я передаю в него название нового объекта `data` и его будущий номер `num`. У меня есть односвязный список.

Моя идея такова: найти предшественника по номеру, извлечь у него ссылку на потомка, указать вместо нее ссылку на новый объект и уже в него помещать извлеченную ссылку. Вопрос как извлечь ссылку и передать её? И вообще можно ли так сделать?

```
public static void addTo(String data, int num) {
    int count = 0;
    Node1 elem = new Node1();
    elem.data = data;
    Node1 temp=head;
    while (count < num) {
        if (num - count == 1){
            //temp=temp.next;
            //count ++;
        }
        //else
    }
}
```

Comment: почему бы просто не воспользоваться встроенными методами вставки в List?

Comment: Какими методами? и Как?

Comment: Гугл говорит что есть метод `add(int index, T element);`

Comment: Так сделать можно, только зачем коментировать код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прокручиваем список, доходя до требуемого элемента и увеличивая при этом счетчик индекса. После окончания цикла у вас будет ссылка.

```
public static void addTo(String data, int num) {
    int count = 0;
    Node1 elem = new Node1();
    elem.data = data;  
    Node1 temp=head;
    Node1 ref = temp;    
    while (count < num && temp != null) { // прокручиваем список пока не дойдем до num                             
        ref = temp;  // сохраняем ссылку на предыдущий элемент          
        temp=temp.next; // двигаемся к следующему элементу           
        count ++;
    }        
    if (ref == null) {
        head = elem;
    } else {             
        Node1 tmp = ref.next;
        ref.next = elem;
        elem.next = tmp;               
    } 
}
```